# Is the write() function in C blocking or non-blocking?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I looked on the Linux man pages for the answer but can't seem to find it. I know that `read()` is blocking but I'm still not sure about `write()`.
Can anyone point me to any documentation for clarification?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. If the write buffer is full, the write can block. You can certainly deadlock yourself with reads and writes. (The file descriptor would need to be made non-blocking explicitly to not suffer from this.)

Comment: It depends on the attributes of the filedescriptor you're writing into.

Comment: Blocking would mean that write doesnt return till the write is finished. Define 'finished'. It will return once it has done enough to allow the write operation to be completed at some point (ie it has the data and you can release the buffer), but is the data on disk, perhaps, is it in the remote machines TCP stack,doubtful

Comment: There is no write in C. There is in unix/posix.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read POSIX on [`read()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) and 
[`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html).  See also functions such as [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) and [`pipe()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html).

It depends on the attributes of the file descriptor you're reading from or writing to (think `O_NONBLOCK`, for example), and on the underlying file type (disk file vs pipe vs FIFO vs socket vs character or block special), and so on.

Succinctly, both `read()` and `write()` can be blocking or non-blocking, depending on circumstances.